# "Please give me until tomorrow morning" Is this expression correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, objects

https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/business-material/suggesting-solutions-to-problems

This is an English lesson material that is used in an online English class.  Please look at the bottom of PART B_2.  Anne says **"Please give me until tomorrow morning."**  Is this sentence correct though it has no direct object in it despite having an indirect object? I wonder whether this is a correct expression or just a typo.

Comment: It's absolutely normal. You could follow it with something like 'to fix your car', or 'to finish this task' but often we don't need to do that if that thing is the topic of the conversation.

Comment: She has just said that she will contact 'other suppliers'. She asks to be given the time until the next morning to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence is correct. The direct object (the thing directly given to the indirect object "me") is "until tomorrow morning". That might not seem like a DO since it is a prepositional phrase, but it does perform that function. If you like, you can infer an actual nominal phrase as the DO:

> Please give me [[an amount of time extending]] until tomorrow morning.

In practice, no one would actually say that. The elliptical version (without the text in double-brackets) is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "*until tomorrow morning*" is the direct object of "give".

This phrase is understood to mean "***the time** until tomorrow morning*", which, in this form, is clearly enough the direct object of "give".